# Intent recycling in MainActivty

Tags: android, android-intent, keylistener

I am attempting to start an intent on my MainActivity class after receiving an entry from an EditText field.  I pass some data with extras.  In my MainActivity I check to see if there are any extras from an Intent.  If so I process the data in an asynchronous task.  The problem is that my MainActivity goes through the process twice of checking for the extras from an Intent and eventually the program bombs.  It is very confusing and I will show below how the program flows.  First below is the initiation of the intent in another activity below the MainActivity.

```
   thisLocation = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.restlocation);

        thisLocation.setOnKeyListener(new View.OnKeyListener() {
            public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
                if((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER)  ||
                        (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER)) {
                    String location = thisLocation.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("Location in key listener", location);
                    try
                    {
                    List<Address> foundGeocode = null;

                    foundGeocode = new Geocoder(getApplicationContext()).getFromLocationName(location, 1);
                    double  newlat = foundGeocode.get(0).getLatitude(); //getting latitude
                    double  newlng = foundGeocode.get(0).getLongitude();//getting longitude
                    Log.d("Lat in key listener", String.valueOf(newlat));
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
                    intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                    intent.putExtra("lat", String.valueOf(lat));
                    intent.putExtra("lng", String.valueOf(lng));
                    startActivity(intent);

                    }

                    catch (IOException e) {
                        Log.e("Geocode", String.valueOf(e));
                    }

    return true;
    }
    return false;
   }
 });
```

I can tell from my logs that the processing goes through the above routine twice before going to the MainActivity.  After the first time through the listener, the logcat shows the tag 'MapActivity' and the Text of "onDestroy leaving light on for com.example.herbx.Restaurant" which is the above activity.  The next time through I enter my MainActivity which also goes through the below logic twice each time preceded by the following message on my logcat:  Tag = MapActivity  Text=Recycling map object.

Next below is the MainActivity processing of the extras from the Intent received from the above activity.

```
    protected void onCreate(Bubdke savedInstanceState) {
       ......  intialization code

        Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();
    if(extras != null)
    {

        lat = Float.parseFloat(extras.getString("lat"));
        lng = Float.parseFloat(extras.getString("lng"));
        Log.d("lat=", String.valueOf(lat));
        NewMap(lat, lng);  // This is an asynchronous task
    }
       }
```

Below is a dump of my logcat showing where I logged certain data.

```
    03-20 19:21:30.256: D/Location in key listener(4045): Peoria
    03-20 19:21:30.519: D/Lat in key listener(4045): 40.6936488
    03-20 19:21:30.616: D/MapActivity(4045): onDestroy leaving the lights on for com.example.herb4.Restaurant@40fc2f88
    03-20 19:21:30.736: D/Location in key listener(4045): Peoria
    03-20 19:21:30.986: D/Lat in key listener(4045): 40.6936488
    03-20 19:21:31.016: I/Choreographer(4045): Skipped 45 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    03-20 19:21:31.168: W/MapActivity(4045): Recycling dispatcher android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher@40cf8f38
    03-20 19:21:31.207: V/MapActivity(4045): Recycling map object.
    03-20 19:21:31.426: D/lat=(4045): 40.9040412902832
    03-20 19:21:31.746: D/newmap addr=(4045): W 7th StMinonk, IL 61760
    03-20 19:21:31.896: W/MapActivity(4045): Recycling dispatcher android_maps_conflict_avoidance.com.google.googlenav.datarequest.DataRequestDispatcher@40cf8f38
    03-20 19:21:31.948: V/MapActivity(4045): Recycling map object.
    03-20 19:21:32.166: D/lat=(4045): 40.9040412902832
    03-20 19:21:32.206: D/GetRestaurant lat=(4045): 40.9040412902832
    03-20 19:21:32.387: D/newmap addr=(4045): W 7th StMinonk, IL 61760
    03-20 19:21:32.446: I/Choreographer(4045): Skipped 69 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    03-20 19:21:32.726: D/dalvikvm(4045): GREF has increased to 201
    03-20 19:21:32.956: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(4045): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
    03-20 19:21:32.956: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(4045):   in android.view.ViewRootImpl@4109f880
    03-20 19:21:32.956: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(4045):   0: sent at 15675516000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_ENTER, scanCode=28, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=15675516, downTime=15675423, deviceId=0, source=0x101 }
    03-20 19:21:33.166: E/InputEventReceiver(4045): Exception dispatching input event.
    03-20 19:21:33.166: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4045): Exception in MessageQueue callback: handleReceiveCallback
    03-20 19:21:33.256: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4045): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0
   03-20 19:21:33.256: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4045):    at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
   03-20 19:21:33.256: E/MessageQueue-JNI(4045):    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:304)
```

So my question is why does the program go through the logic twice when I enter data in the first activity above?  It is very confusing and the net result I get a an erorr saying Exception in MessageQueue callbackL handleReceiveCallback and an IndexOutOfBoundsException.
If anyone needs more information on this confusing issue please let me know.

Below is the code in which it appears I get the nullexception but I get the first log of "GetRestaurant lat=" but I don't get the second log which is "GetRestaurant try".  I have no idea where a nullexception can occur between those 2 logs.  Also, I come into this routine from other sources and it works, just doesn't work in this context.

```
 List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
URL url;
Log.d("GetRestaurant lat=", thislat);  // this gets logged
try {
 Log.d("GetRestaurant try", "");   //  this doesn't get logged
String query = "?lat=" + thislat + "&lng=" + thislng + "&uid=&vegkey=1";
url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:8000/herbivorenew/webservice/frontpage1.php" + query);
HttpURLConnection httpConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
int responseCode = httpConnection.getResponseCode();
if(responseCode == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
    InputStream in = httpConnection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(in));
String line;

int x=0;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
    result = new ArrayList<String>(Arrays.asList(line.split("&")));
     Log.d("GetRestaurant result=", String.valueOf(result.get(0)));
    x++;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post the complete stack trace? And please indicate which line has what line number.

Comment: Why would lat be different in the AsyncTask compared to what you get in the intent? One says 40.9040412902832, the latter 40.6936488? And why do you pass the double parameters as String instead of double ?

Comment: I realized I picked the wrong lat value when passing it to the asnyctask and have corrected that.  I don't have a reason for using a string instead of double other than I am a newbie as you can tell and am trying to learn the different parsing methods for passing data.  I am a C# programmer trying to make the conversion to Java.  Thanks for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

onKey() is called twice, once when the key is pressed and once when the key is released. What you need to do is something like this:

```
public boolean onKey(View v, int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {

        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_DPAD_CENTER ||
            keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_ENTER) {
            if (event.getAction()!=KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                return true;
            }

            // here goes your code

            return true;
        }

        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your feedback.  I made the correction and reran and now I only get one response but I still get the same error at the end shown on the logcat above.  The final errors appear to occur in the asyntask routine.  Do you know what could be causing the above errors?

Comment: Well it's a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 0, size is 0 so I guess you're accessing an empty list or something with index 0, but your stack trace doesn't show the line in your code and your asynctask code is not posted so there's really no way to answer that question. You should either check if your list or array is intialized properly or post the stacktrace and the relevant piece of code

Comment: I moved my logic down so that I made sure the execution of the asyntask was the last thing I do during the onCreate process and that appears to make it worked.  Thanks for your help.